# Electronic detector to measure of distance?

Tags: measurement, microchip, distance, detector

I am not well known about electronic and it is my first question here, beforehand sorry for not qualified question. Let me try to explain what I am looking for:

Is there chip or any another electronic device to measure how much distance was passed? Like it does Pedometer. What is principle of this mechanism?

Comment: Global Positioning System ie gps

Comment: Odometer for wheeled vehicles.

Comment: What precision do you have in mind? Measuring distance for a vehicle? Per pedes? Range in micrometers or light years? One tape measure is usually sufficient :-)

Comment: Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedometer ? There it says: "*A pedometer is a device, ... that counts each step a person takes by detecting the motion of the person's hands or hips*" So it counts how many steps you took. It does not measure distance. Taking small or large steps has influence on the actual distance covered. i.e. a Pedometer measures the distance indirectly. A pedometer can be made using an **acceleration sensor** which can be in the form of a chip.

Comment: I would add: optical flow sensors and IMUs (for the IMU just integrate the output).

Comment: Thank you for response, I will detailed my question soon

Comment: position is done with inertial MEM’s gyro’s and accelerometer with CPU process of sensor data, to avoid drift that occurs from 2 order integration of g.  Doppler uses RF triangulation of GPS with differential land based RF used on golf courses for best resolution together with GPS 4 channels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what your question is.  I'll take it as asking about a electronic pedometer.

Yes, that is possible.  Mechanical pedometers work by detecting the up and down bounces of your body as you walk.  This is done with a mass on a spring, and a mechanism to increment a mechanical counter each cycle.

You can electronically sense the same up and down bouncing of the body with something called a *accelerometer*.  These put out a signal proportional to the acceleration they are subjected to.

There are several different technologies, trading off cost and accuracy.  Those used for inertial navigation of aircraft, for example, cost 10s of $k.  Fortunately for you, there are also devices available at the other end of that tradeoff.  MEMS technology allows for cheap accelerometers on chips, and cost 10s of cents to a few dollars.  These are what cell phones use to determine which way you are holding them, and rotate the screen accordingly, for example.

A cheap MEMS accelerometer is plenty good enough to detect the up/down bouncing of the body due to walking.  In fact, I'm pretty sure there is a smart phone app that uses the built-in accelerometer to do exactly that.